# Error 400 when adding Google Analytics Script

Tags: javascript, django, google-analytics, http-status-code-400

I put a Google Analytics tag in [the header of my website](https://github.com/antoinecomp/django3-personal-portfolio/blob/main/portfolio/templates/portfolio/base.html):

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-V51YR2QF7N"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-V51YR2QF7N');
</script>
```

But even after reloading the website in my pythonanywhere integrated development environment, still no statistics appear.

I ran this code locally and here are the errors:

```
(dja_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Projects\django3-personal-portfolio>python manage.py runserver
Looks like no local file. You must be on production
Looks like no local file. You must be on production
Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
blog.Blog: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the BlogConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
portfolio.Project: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the PortfolioConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.

System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).
May 30, 2021 - 21:20:44
Django version 3.2.3, using settings 'personal_portfolio.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[30/May/2021 21:22:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 143
[30/May/2021 21:22:47] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 143
```

Comment: Are there any errors visible in the browser's web developer console when you access the site when it's hosted on PythonAnywhere?

Answer (score 0):

One shouldn't test GoogleAnalytics accuracy on its website with a browser using anti-tracking addons